# Inno Setup IDE and ISCC/ISPP passing define

Tags: command-line-arguments, inno-setup

I would like to use both the InnoIDE and ISCC/ISPP, the difference being that I would like to pass in a parameter, which will override a #define in the script.

In the command line I can pass `/Dmyarg=myvalue`.  That is the same as `#define myarg myvalue` in the script.

Sadly, the script takes precedence over the command line value.  I know, as I tried.  I can obviously comment out the `#define` in the script and the command line define will work, however then I will not be able to use the IDE to build.

Is it possible to set a `#define` inside InnoIDE somewhere for the project or is there some means to have the command line `#define` take precedence?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your script, do something like this:

```
#ifndef myarg
# define myarg "mydefault"
#endif
```

Now, if you compile in the IDE or if you use the command line without specifying `/Dmyarg="something"`, then it will use the default specified in the script.  Otherwise, if you do specify something on the command line then it will use that instead.

Comment: I did not realize that the scripting language supports C-style preprocessor compiler definitions.  Thanks!